# Android debug/run configurations

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration, ddms

I am trying to figure out what exactly is the difference between debug configuration and run configuration. When is one used and when the other.
When I look in them they are both the same for my application:

1. Launch default activity
2. Choose deployment target automatically

Comment: What I would really want to know, is how to detect which mode my code is in. That seems to be near to impossible in Eclipse/ADT. Should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A debug configuration packages your app with debugging info so you can use break points and step through the code as it runs.

A run configuration is what you would do to get a final product type apk.

Comment: When I "Export" my apk does it automatically use the run configuration?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does.  If it doesn't it should give a warning.  There's also amanifest attribute called 'debuggable' that forces a debug compile when set to true so you'll have to watch out for that.

Comment: No, this isn't correct.  They're configurations for how the code runs, not how the code is built.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you bring up the configuration window, the buttons in the lower right are different.  One says "Debug" and another says "Run."

Dalvik behaves differently when a debugger is attached, take a look in the Android source tree [(availabe here and many other places, or your local tree in android/dalvik/docs/debugger.html)](http://www.milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/debugger.html).  That's true for the same code; running the same instance of your app with a debugger attached, and without a debugger attached, are different experiences.  It also depends on the version of Android you're running.

Run configuration doesn't recompile your app, it just doesn't turn on some debugging behavior in Dalvik.  For my app, that's a huge speed increase; your experience may vary.